# Get html data over Get Request C#

Tags: c#, php, html

I made a little API in PHP that return some user information after a successful login. The information will be returned in HTML format with Paragraph ID's. Here's an example of data return in HTML:

```
<body>
    <p id="msg">Successful login</p>
    <p id="uid">1</p>
    <p id="username">Joey</p>
    <p id="email">Test@gmail.com</p>
    <p id="hwid"></p>
    <p id="funds">0</p>
</body>
```

So I want to post the login data to the API and get the information by HTML-IDs.

**The API:**

```
api.php?set=login&username={USER}&password={PASS}
```

Comment: And your question is?...

Comment: Look at the WebClient / HttpWebRequest classes - XML would be a better response format unless you specifically just want to display it.

Comment: You may want to get the data by html-ids...but you shouldn't. You have PHP and C# at your disposal. Keep that information in variables...

Answer (score 0):

First up - I'd suggest using JSON instead of HTML for this - PHP has json_encode and json_decode - and then you can add the JSON.Net nuget package to deserialize on your end very easily.

```
echo json_encode(resultObject)
```

and then in c#

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ResultType>(downloadedString)
```

Then all you need to do is look into HttpWebRequest and WebRequest, to download that string from your api

That would look something like

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create("http://url/api");
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
{
    String downloadedString = reader.ReadToEnd();
}
```

Alternatively, you can process the HTML as XML

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(response.GetResponseStream());
String msg = doc.GetElementById("msg").Value;
```